# ReactJS Handle API error in redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, middleware, http-status-code-401

What I am searching for is a generic way to handle API error codes. For example:

- If there is a `error.status.code` `401` `(in this case the 401 would be unauthorized)`.
  I want to dispatch a certain action for example clean up the redux state and that the user has to login again.
- If there is a `error.status.code` `404` `(not found)`. I want to redirect or push the user to a certain route.

These action are all equal behaviour for every action.

---

The issue with the following function is that it doesn't have dispatch avaiable. I am searching a way to implement this behaviour in the redux middleware. To be honest there isn't much information about it avaiable.

** My API function:**

```
export const fetchApi = (url, config) => {
  return fetch(url, config)
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
          if (res.statusCode === 401) {
              // dispatch an action, not possible dispatch is not avaible
          }
      }
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.text();
      }
    })
    .then((text) => (text.length ? JSON.parse(text) : {}));
};
```

I am looking in somewhat of this direction:

**store.js**

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { persistedReducer } from './config';

export default () => {
  const middleware = [thunkMiddleware];
  const middleWareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(
    ...middleware,
    thunk.withExtraArgument({
      apiFetch: (...args) =>
        fetchApi(...args).catch((err) => {
          // general error handling when fetchApi has certain errors
          //  that needs to change something in redux store
          if (err.statusCode === 401) {
            //dispatch clean all data action
            store.dispatch({ type: 'reset' });
            //location.href redirect or reload
          }
          // reject the promise
          return Promise.reject(err);
        }),
    })
  );

  const composeEnhancers =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeEnhancers(middleWareEnhancer)
  );

  let persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { store, persistor };
};
```

I am just shooting blind for possible solutions. If you have any suggestions feel free to comment it.

Update:
When I add this middleware. I can listen to the payload from the actions and see if one throws a 'unauthorized'. Based on that I can dispatch an action. I don't know how water proof this solution is.

**Update:**

Middleware:

```
const authInterceptor = ({ dispatch }) => (next) => (
  action
) => {
 
  if (action.payload === 'unauthorized') {
    dispatch(something());
  } else {
    next(action);
  }
};
```

**Store.js**

```
export default () => {
  const middleware = [thunkMiddleware, authInterceptor];
  const middleWareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middleware);
  const composeEnhancers =
    (true && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
    compose;
  let store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    composeEnhancers(middleWareEnhancer)
  );

  let persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { store, persistor };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, as it seems your issue is with redux-thunk, redux architecture. look to deal with redux we have three main files we are supposed to creat
the action files, the reducers files, and finally the store (some people might write the store directly in the root file like App.js or index.js)
any redux-thunk logic must live within the action files that way you are gonna git dispatch as a props passed to your action
here is an example
if we have an action called signupUserAsync to signup our users

```
const signupUserAsync = (props) => {
 return (dispatch ) => {
  Api.post(/*whaterever is our URL, pramas, data*/).then(res=> dispatch(saveDataAction(res.data))
 }
}
```

with that, it will work for you.
and you can find out more through there docs in here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

or in this case, you could try this -->

```
export const fetchApi = (url, config) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
 fetch(url, config)
    .then((res) => {
      if (!res.ok) {
          if (res.statusCode === 401) {
              // Now hopefully you will have the dispatch function working
          }
      }
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.text();
      }
    })
    .then((text) => (text.length ? JSON.parse(text) : {}));
 }
};
```

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the redux architecture. This part is working fine. I have my thunk actions, reducers, selectors etc. I am looking for a propper way to generic handle certain API errors. Like 401, 404, 500 etc.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer, please try it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: This isn't going to work as well. Because you call the fetchApi function inside a thunk action. So the thunk action: const someThunkAction () => { return (dispatch, getState) => { return fetchApi('/something/url/data', { config object}).then.((res) => dispatch()).catch((err)=> dispatch())}}. Inside the fetchApi function there is no dispatch available to do something with a 401 or 404